# Why do these two relations stand?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

I want to find the cost of the following algorithm in average case:

```
Quicksort(A,p,r)
      if p<r then
         q<- partition(A,p,r)
         Quicksort(A,p,q-1)
         Quicksort(A,q+1,r)
```

We suppose that we are lucky-unlucky alternately.

L: lucky, U: Unlucky

Why do these two relations stand:

L(n)=2U(n/2)+Θ(n)

U(n)=L(n-1)+Θ(n)

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that alternating lucky and unlucky pivot choices means that whenever you make an unlucky choice, the remaining subproblem will be solved with a lucky pivot choice, and vice versa.

Second, notice that a lucky pivot choice will split the input into two equally sized subproblems that are each half the size of the original. An unlucky choice, on the other hand, leaves a single subproblem that is nearly the same size as the original (because either every item in the input is larger than the pivot item, or is smaller).

From those two observations, it should be obvious why the cost of a lucky subproblem (L(n)) and the cost of an unlucky subproblem (U(N)) are as shown.